# In Bash: Read two integers from a file while ignoring characters between them.

Tags: bash, file

I'm very new to bash and am attempting to write a script to do the following.

I have a file: file.txt which looks like

`13, 243`

I would like to have a bash script read the two integers and store them as variables

I have tried the following (note that fileName is a string which contains the filename):

```
read -r line <$fileName
line=${line//,/}
for i in $line; do echo $i; done;
```

Which will read the line, remove the "," and then print out the two integers.  I am unsure however how to go about actually storing these two integers in two different variables.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: You probably want to use `"$fileName"` (with quotes). Otherwise this will break if `$fileName` contains whitespace (ie. a space). It's a *very* good habit in shell scripting to always quote filenames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
line=$(cat testfile | sed 's/ //g')
args=(${line//,/ })
x="${args[0]}"
y="${args[1]}"
echo $x # 13
echo $y # 243
```

Comment: This works fine, but now how do I store args[0] and args[1] in two variables and have them recognized as integers?

For example if I want to have x = 13 and y = 243, how do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `cut`:

```
$ echo '13, 243' | cut -d, -f1
13
$ echo '13, 243' | cut -d, -f2
 243
```

The extra space often isn't a problem, but if you want to get rid of it:

```
$ echo '13, 243' | cut -d, -f2 | tr -d ' '
243
```

In a script, you would use this as:

```
var1=$(echo "$line" | cut -d, -f1)
var2=$(echo "$line" | cut -d, -f2 | tr -d ' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you simply need to remove ',' from your input, you can do this quickly and easily with sed:

sed 's/,//g' file

Answer (score 0):

```
read file.txt REPLY
#Read into REPLY variable

var1="${REPLY#*, }"
#Strip off the pattern "*, " from string beginning, store in another var
var2="${REPLY%,*}"
#Strip off the pattern ",*" from string end, store in another var
```

Note: untested, but it should only need minor tweaking

Comment: Also note that `#` and `%` are non-portable `bash` features. They don't work on all Bourne-compatible shells.